# Cordova QrCode Reader

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I'm developing an app in phonegap/cordova that needs to read qrcodes. Through my search I think I have to use a plugin, specific for android and one specific to ios. I know that BarcodeScanner is a good solution but I can't understand how do I develop an app in phonegap and have at the same time an app in android and ios. If I make changes in the phonegap project, that work in ios and android, what do I have to do so the changes are applied to both ios and android projects?

Thanks

Comment: After many search I found this post: http://www.christianengvall.se/phonegap-and-multiple-platforms/ I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

QR-code generates as per the compiled platform. If you compiled the app in android platform the QR code supports only for that particular platform. I used the remote git account and tested by installing using QRcode, it works fine.